# Regular expression configuration

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file with data like the sample below, I extract the data from the text file using regular expressions.

```
 Card number: 99280*********8823, SEQ: 182
Current session ID: 182
21/01/2021 08:46:49 : Selected language : French
21/01/2021 08:46:49 : Chip application : NO Active 
 21/01/2021 09:53:03 : Returned code : 0
 21/01/2021 09:53:03 : Pin entered
 21/01/2021 09:53:09 : Transaction selected: FastCash 40000 on ATM: Y6154514
 21/01/2021 09:53:10 : Returned code : 0
21/01/2021 09:53:13  : FastCash Authorization requested
21/01/2021 09:53:14  : FastCash Authorized
Returned code : 0, STAN: 680017
21/01/2021 09:53:27  : Cash dispensed
21/01/2021 09:53:28  : Card ejected
21/01/2021 09:53:29  : Card taken
21/01/2021 09:53:32  : Dispense details:
->cass 1: 0 x 5000 MMM, cass 2: 4 x 10000 MMM
->cass 3: 0 x 10000 MMM, cass 4: 0 x 20000 MMM
------->Total cash dispensed: 40000 MMM
21/01/2021 09:53:32  : Cash presented
21/01/2021 09:53:32  : Waiting for cash to be taken
21/01/2021 09:53:33  : Cash taken
21/01/2021 09:53:39  : Transaction completed
 21/01/2021 09:53:41 : Session terminated
```

Here is the regex used :

```
regex = r"number:\s(\d+\*+\d+).*?ID:\s*(\d*).*?ATM:\s(\w+).*?STAN:\s(\d+).*?Total cash dispensed:\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s+([a-zA-Z0-9]+).*?completed[\r\n]+(.*?)\s:"
```

The output is :

```
[('99280*********8823', '182', 'Y6154514', '680017', '40000', 'MMM', ' 21/01/2021 09:53:41')]
```

My question is: Is there is a way to configure the regular expression from a config file or an env file where the wanted fields are picked, to get for example only the first element on the list of tuples or the first and the second or the first and last....

Comment: I don't know about a direct way, but I think you can save your regex in a JSON file ( Different fields in different attributes of the object ) and then parsing the file in a dictionary and use it on call.

Comment: yes am saving everything in JSON and am using it in a rest API but how can I parse it in a dictionary and use it on call, do you care to elaborate on that?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-json-to-dictionary-in-python/) article and see if it helps. It is explaining how to parse JSON as a dictionary in python.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand, regular expressions are simply strings (plus minus some details), so they can be created and manipulated with the usual string-related stuff.

So you can split your regex string into one string for each element and then add all the strings together, with a boolean for each string saying whether it should be included or not. The boolean variables can then easily be stored and read from any kind of file.

Consider the following "file" from which to read data:

```
clouds:1
sun:2
dirt:3
pixel:4
```

Now create your regex as follows:

```
rclouds = r"clouds:(\d).*?"
rsun = r"sun:(\d).*?"
rdirt = r"dirt:(\d).*?"
rpixel = r"pixel:(\d).*?"
bclouds = 0
bsun = 1
bdirt = 1
bpixel = 0
regex = rclouds*bclouds + rsun*bsun + rdirt*bdirt + rpixel*bpixel
```

`re.findall(regex,<however_you_access_the_above_"file">)` will return the values for "sun" and "dirt", since bsun and bdirt are True and bclouds and bpixel are false.

Now you just make a .txt (or whatever) file where a user can specify 0 or 1 for each element and you read bclouds,...,bpixel from that file instead of specifying them in the code.